# docker build Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image but i am getting the following failure.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tv-fonts/tv-fonts_1.1-8_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:19e2e7a51c83dcf616a8f009c1cc39dc8c1755135983e5ec4abeacefbf977585
    - MD5Sum:482a1f68c5ffff5117b2c6b25b740624 [weak]
    - Filesize:2144504 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:fb6550c1d066571f3cee715bbaaf4528f547032e101b23f057a42c55c0dade84
    - MD5Sum:4c118e8d7b54b7f23af0093b7a2dbef4 [weak]
    - Filesize:246436 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 19:18:45 +0000
```

I already searched for this issue but without a solution working for me. I tried to clean the apt-cache like below, but also useless.

```
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
       apt-get clean && \
       apt-get -y update
```

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:17:20 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm
```

any idea?

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile? Which image is your dockerfile base of?

Comment: i try to build the following: https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/geoserver/

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget and dpkg command like to:

```
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -O - http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tv-fonts/tv-fonts_1.1-8_all.deb | wc -l > /directory/tv-fonts_1.1-8_all.deb.deb
RUN dpkg -i --force-depends /directory/tv-fonts_1.1-8_all.deb.deb
```

You can find more info about wget best practices in [dockerhub](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)